# Nsight showing a discontinuous OpenGL pixel history?

Tags: opengl, nsight

I'm trying to figure out how a particular fragment is getting its color. The pixel should not be brown (R=136,G=109,B=95) and yet it is. I loaded up NSight and ran a pixel history. But I'm not understanding what it's showing me.

`Event #1787` failed the depth test, so presumably that event had no effect. So how does it go from R=135,G=206,B=235 in the "RT After" of `Event #2` to the brown we see in "RT Before" of `Event #1830`?

[image]

Comment: Different framebuffer maybe? Show your code, otherwise everything will just be random guessing.

Comment: @BDL I don't think it's separate framebuffer; it's all just rendering to the backbuffer, and then SwapBuffer at the end. I also noticed the Event# are wrong; the history shows changes long prior to 1830. I've wrote Nsight off as just having broken OpenGL pixel history support; it must only work on D3D11.